# Match pattern in each word inside a sentece

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following pattern: `/*.a*.b*.c/` which will match any input that includes `a` `b` and `c` in that order.

So the following strings will match my pattern:

- `555  a  fgb ccc`
- `a b c`
- `atbtc`

What i would like to achieve is a match only in whole words and not in the entire sentence. so the following string will match:

- `i want abc`
  but the following will NOT match:
- `a b c`

I solved it by doing str.split(" ") and run my pattern on each word separately but i'm sure there is a way to achieve it with a single regex match.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `*.a*.b*.c` is your pattern? It throws an exception because you cannot quantify the string start. I think you have `/.*a.*b.*c/`. Try [`^.*a\w*b\w*c.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/bW0aO1/2). Or do you want any words that contain `a`, `b` and `c` in any order?

Comment: Um, is't the `.` and `*` switched!?

Comment: `/abc\b/i` ? You will need a word boundary.

Comment: I think you need a better example.  How about "I'm taking antibiotics"?

Comment: @AlanMoore I'm taking antibiotics should match. Since it has a word that contains `a``b``c` in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `.` with `[^\s]` (any character other than white space) in your regex.

```
/[^\s]*a[^\s]*b[^\s]*c/
```

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF4iD7/1)

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`/[ ]+(abc)[ ]+/g` should resolve your case

Comment: This will only match words that contains the substring "abc" which is not what is asked. And this will not match words at the beginning or the end of the sentence (without a space before or after them).

Comment: It's more like `/ *([a-z]*a[a-z]*b[a-z]*c[a-z]*) */g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `/([^ ]*a[^ ]*)( )*([^ ]*b[^ ]*)( )*([^ ]*c[^ ]*)( )*/`

Then if you want to capture the words containing a, b and c. You need to use `match`.

With this regex the words will be at position 1, 3 and 5 according to matching parenthesis.

To have more details, and build your regex you can use https://regex101.com/